# AWS RDS SSL Expiry Notifications

Tags: amazon-rds

Does anyone know if AWS RDS generates an event for SSL expiry. 2 years ago a certificate expired due to the change that happens every 5 years. I would like to trigger an event that notifies me when we are close to expiry each day. I can't seem to find any documentation on the event pattern or ID, does one exist? My other option is to run a lambda that does a `describe-certificate` every so often and alerts me if it's within x amount of days of expiry. I would prefer the former event driven approach over the latter.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to look for expiry notification with a lambda function